# How do you access global variables updated in functions in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have two functions that update previously defined global variables. When I want to add the updated versions of the variables and print them to the console, JavaScript adds the original values that the variables were defined as. How do I add the updated values? I have included the code below.

```js
var number1 = 1;
var number2 = 2;

function function1() {
   number1 = 3; 
}

function function2() {
  number2 = 4;
}

console.log(number1 + number 2);
```

Comment: The problem is you don't call the functions...

Comment: For the record, you should not make a habit of structuring your code around globals. Use functions which return values instead of mutating values where possible, and use namespacing to avoid polluting global scope with variables that don't belong there.

Answer (score 2):

A function does nothing if it isn't called. Call them:

```js
var number1 = 1;
var number2 = 2;

function function1() {
   number1 = 3; 
}

function function2() {
  number2 = 4;
}

function1();
function2();

console.log(number1 + number2);
```

Comment: Seriously, that edit was borderline vandalism. Putting some `document.write` when OP already has the right practice of using `console.log` ???

Comment: From the trollish sounding edit description, I'm guessing it was an attempt at saying mutable globals are bad practice, so you might as well use all the bad practices.

Comment: @4castle In fact we cornered the editor. He just didn't know there was a boxed console in the snippet... He's sorry...